# Sum rows and columns in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following Sql Query

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT APLICACION_ID, CASE WHEN ESTADO_CASO ='6' THEN 'Pendiente'
WHEN ESTADO_CASO ='7' THEN 'En_Proceso'
WHEN ESTADO_CASO ='8' THEN 'En_Seguimiento'
WHEN ESTADO_CASO ='4' THEN 'Para_version_HCECLI'
ELSE 'XXXX' END ESTADO_CASO, COUNT(*) CANTIDAD
FROM SERV_CASO
WHERE serv_caso.tercero_caso = '90'
GROUP BY APLICACION_ID, ESTADO_CASO
)
PIVOT
(
SUM(CANTIDAD)
FOR ESTADO_CASO
IN ('Pendiente','En_Proceso','En_Seguimiento','Para_version_HCECLI')
)ORDER BY 1;
```

Which returns me the following table

```
APLICACION_ID  'Pendiente'  'En_Proceso' 'En_Seguimiento' 'Para_version_HCECLI'
Primer item        1            4               3                  9
segundoitem        2                            2
```

But I have to do a sum per row and columns avoiding the fields that are blank that are null to get the following result when performing the query

```
APLICACION_ID  'Pendiente'  'En_Proceso' 'En_Seguimiento' 'Para_version_HCECLI'  'Total'
Primer item        1            4               3                  9                17
segundoitem        2                            2                                   4 
Total              3            4               5                  9                21
```

Comment: It is unclear why you would have two rows for the same key.  Something is not being explained correctly.

Comment: It´s diferent row  'Total' and Total

Comment: @DaniUrrego You have two rows with the same `Aplication_ID = Primer Item`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are getting two rows for the same `APLICACION_ID`, but conditional aggregation with `GROUPING SETS` is simpler and more powerful:

```
SELECT APLICACION_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ESTADO_CASO = '6' THEN 1 END) as Pendiente,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ESTADO_CASO = '7' THEN 1 END) as En_Proceso,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ESTADO_CASO = '8' THEN 1 END) as En_Seguimiento,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ESTADO_CASO = '4' THEN 1 END) as Para_version_HCECLI,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ESTADO_CASO IN ('6', '7', '8', '4') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total
FROM SERV_CASO
WHERE serv_caso.tercero_caso = '90'
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (APLICACION_ID), () );
```